# How to find the normailzer of $R_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ in $SL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $p$ be prime and $F_p$ the field with $p$ elements. Let $G=SL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$.
Let $B=B_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be the group of upper triangular $n\times{}n$ matrices with determinant $1$.
Let $R=R_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be the group of upper triangular $n\times{}n$ matrices with $1$s in the main diagonal.

I want to show that $N_G(R)=B$, i.e. the normalizer of $R$ in $G$ is $B$.

I can show that $B\subseteq{}N_G(R)$, by showing that $R$ is normal in $B$: this is because $R$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi{}$ from $B$ to the group of diagonal matrices, that turns all numbers above the main diagonal to $0$.

However, I am not sure how to show that $N_G(R)\subseteq{}B$.

Comment: Look at the action of $R$ on the vector space $V = F_p^n$. It fixes a unique subspace $V_1$ of dimension $1$. So $N_G(R)$ must also fix $V_1$. Similarly, in its induced action of $V/V_1$ it fixes a unique subspace $V_2/V_1$ of dimension $1$, also fixed by $N_G(R)$. Carrying on like this, we see that $N_G(R)$ fixes al the subspaces in a chain $V_1 < V_2 < \cdots V_n = N$ where $\dim(V_i)=i$, and $B$ is exactly the subgroup of $G$ with that property.

Comment: You mean ***upper triangular*** $n \times n$ matrices, right?  I don't know what an ***upper diagonal*** matrix is.

Comment: @RobertLewis edited. thanks.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't quite understand... why does the action fix a unique subspace of dimention 1? and what does that mean: fixing every element of $V_1$ or preserving elements of $V_1$ inside $V_1$?

Comment: If the matrices $A$ are acting on column vectors $v$ by $v \mapsto Av$, then it is not hard to show that the only eigenspace is that spanned by $(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. My comment was intended as a hint.